# Using "in the middle" to describe a number smaller than A and bigger than B

Tags: phrase-meaning

The percentages of animals in the zoo:

- Elephants: 3%.
- Lions: 5%.
- Rabbits: 15%.

These are all fake numbers by the way, and I think there is something wrong with this example, but let's focus on the real question here. Is the following example correct? If not, must it be 9% instead of 5% for me to use "in the middle"?

> "The percentages of rabbits and elephants in the zoo are 15% and 3% respectively, and the figure for lions is in the middle, at 5%."

Comment: Seems you're wondering recently how much slop is permissible. First "generally", now "middle".

Comment: It would be more apt to say something like "Rabbits outnumber Elephants five to one, and lions three to one." If Lions were 7% then you might say "in the middle".

Comment: @TimR I find that phrasing ambiguous: is the 3-to-1 ratio between rabbits and lions or between lions and elephants?

Comment: The thrust of the remark is to use **outnumber** and a ratio rather than to say "in the middle". OP appears to be testing how much  wiggle room broad terms like "generally" and "in the middle" allow (which is a matter of opinion) and I think it would be better to seek other ways of expressing things still with broad strokes while at the same time providing more nuance.

Comment: I think your example using 'in the middle' is clear and understandable.  I do agree that 'in between' is more common and idiomatic, though.  I've seen constructs like "somewhere in the middle" when a precise value is not given.

Comment: @TimR yeah that's exactly what I'm trying to do. If I were training to write English as a writer or something, I'd definitely always seek the best ways to express ideas. The thing is, I'm learning to a deadline for my exam. I want something usable in various tests without being unacceptable.

Comment: Answers to questions such as "Is this phrase sufficiently not devoid of meaning that I could get away with using it in an answer on a standardized test?" would be opinions only, and for that reason such questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Am I wrong to suggest that Asking that Question would tend to rule out much chance of understanding JimmyJames wholly correct Answer?

Comment: How could learning to a deadline excuse you from getting it right?

Whether this is about English or maths is a different thing and don't you see, there's no useful difference between 'usable in various tests' and 'without being unacceptable'?

Whether or not you're training to write English as a writer or something, why not always seek the best ways to express ideas?

Answer (score 10):

The use of *in the middle* isn't great.

For clarity, we could consider

> The percentages of rabbits and elephants in the zoo are 15% and 3%, respectively, and the figure for lions is *somewhere in between* at 5%.

**Edit**

or

> ... the figure for lions *lies between them* at 5%.

Comment: I don't think it would be acceptable to use _in the middle_ when quoting statistics.

Comment: Thanks,  @Kate Bunting.   I have edited my answer.

Comment: I thought about _somewhere in between_, too, but don't we know exactly where it is in between?

Comment: I think we may omit that phrase and simply say *and the figure for lions is 9%*.

Comment: "...the figure for lions lies between them, at 5%".

Comment: Thanks, @TonyK.  I have added your suggestion to my answer.

Comment: I really don't  you need a comma there...

Comment: Thanks,  @Lambie.  I've deleted them.

Comment: +1 "somewhere in between" is perfectly idiomatic here.

Comment: Thanks, guys. Why do native speakers use "_somewhere_ in between" when they know the exact percentage? Shouldn't it be "in between"?